# Convert A Date Into Timestamp

Tags: angular

```
I have some question on how to convert from date string to the timestamp format?


getDob(val) {
  val= this.profileForm.get('icnumber').value;
  var Year = val.substring(0, 2);
  var Month = val.substring(2, 4)
  var Day = val.substring(4, 6)

  var cutoff = (new Date()).getFullYear() - 2000

  var dob = Day + '/' + Month + '/' + (Year > cutoff ? '19' : '20') + Year;


  return dob;
}
```

This is a function that I got the string date.  Can any one tell how to do that? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at the date pipe.

```
{{ dateObj | date }}
```

It supports a lot of formatting options as mentioned at https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe